# Upon first using app, an alert asks for a username, which is stored w/ CoreData. Having trouble displaying this stored name in the app's homescreen

Tags: ios, core-data

As the title says, I'm working on creating an app that stores user data and then displays that data at the app's "homescreen" every time you open the app. I've started off with just the username, but I can't seem to get it to work.

When running the app, it never encounters any errors. However after hitting the "Save" button, the label's text is not updated to show the name that was entered. I'm so confused! :/ Would anyone mind taking a quick look if you can?

EDIT: Updated the code. Now I'm getting an error in the "updateName" function. On the line "var person = people[0]" I get the following: "Fatal error: Array index out of range." I don't get why the 0 index wasn't already set as the alert's textfield. Any ideas?

```
class InitialViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {

var didRunBefore: Bool = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().boolForKey("didRunBefore")


@IBOutlet weak var userGreeting: UILabel!


var people = [NSManagedObject]()
var alert = UIAlertController(title: "Hello!", message: "What's your name?", preferredStyle: .Alert)


override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {

    if !didRunBefore {
        getUserName()
        NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setBool(true, forKey: "didRunBefore")
        NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize()
    }
}


override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

    let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
    let managedContext = appDelegate.managedObjectContext!

    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName:"Person")

    var error: NSError?

    let fetchedResults = managedContext.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest, error: &error) as? [NSManagedObject]

    if let results = fetchedResults {
        people = results
    } else {
        println("Could not fetch \(error), \(error!.userInfo)")
    }
}



func getUserName() {

    userGreeting.text = ""


    let saveAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Save", style: .Default) { (action: UIAlertAction!) -> Void in
        let textField = self.alert.textFields![0] as! UITextField
        self.saveName(textField.text)
    }


    let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .Default) { (action: UIAlertAction!) -> Void in
    }

    alert.addTextFieldWithConfigurationHandler {
        (textField: UITextField!) -> Void in
    }

    alert.addAction(saveAction)
    alert.addAction(cancelAction)

    func updateName() {
        var person = people[0]
        if let userName1 = person.valueForKey("name") as? String {
            userGreeting.text = "Hey there, \(userName1)!"
        }
    }

    presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: updateName)

}


 func saveName(name: String) {

    let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
    let managedContext = appDelegate.managedObjectContext!


    let entity1 =  NSEntityDescription.entityForName("Person", inManagedObjectContext: managedContext)
    let person = NSManagedObject(entity: entity1!, insertIntoManagedObjectContext: managedContext)


    person.setValue(name, forKey: "name")


    var error: NSError?
    if !managedContext.save(&error) {
        println("Could not save \(error), \(error?.userInfo)")
    }

    people[0] = person
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

In order to update a UILabel, you have to assign a string to its .text property.  In this case, you have a UILabel called userGreeting.  You never have assigned its text to a value (although I see you reference it twice) , and thus the label will not update.

For example, this would set the label to the name Bill

`userGreeting.text = "Bill"`

Replace "Bill" with your custom name to get your desired result.

Comment: Hmm.. I toyed around with what you had said but still couldn't get the desired result. I edited my original post with what I've done since, does anything stick out?

Comment: Hmm, I'm not really sure after taking a better look at your code.  However, that error, as you already know, tells you that there is no value at your array's index path 0.  This indicates that the array has nothing stored in it.  I would first check (with breakpoints), whether saveName is being called at all, and whether it is being called before updateName as is expected.  If it is being called in the expected order, I would check whether it is being inserted correctly (you can use breakpoints + printout statements to see what people[0] is at runtime at the end of saveName.